# How to listen in two port numbers in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with tomcat 8. this tomcat has a rest web service (in port 8080) that I consume in an android application. Now, I want to put a website in that same tomcat. I'm able to acces the website in this way:

**www.domain.com:8080**

I know that to access the website without the port number I need to change the default tomcat port to 80. But if I do that, my Android application will not be able to access the web service anymore.

So, how can I do this? Access the website without specify the port number and preserve the 8080 port for my android application?

***EDIT:***

This is my server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
    type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
    description="User database that can be updated and saved"
    factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
    pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
            resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>

    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
            prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    </Host>

</Engine>
</Service>
    </Server>
```

***EDIT 2:***

If I run this:

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep 2563 (tomcat PID)
```

I get this:

```
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      2563/java           
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      2563/java
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Tomcat server on two different ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231052/running-tomcat-server-on-two-different-ports)

Comment: This does not work for me. :/

Comment: Just tried it and it worked fine on tomcat 8 locally.  I'm guessing your security settings aren't letting port 80 out of your EC2 instance.

Comment: My security settings of EC2 already allow inbound on port 80 from any source. I checked now.

Comment: Your don't tell us what error message you're getting.

Comment: There is no error message. I check the tomcat log.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add/update new/existing connector in conf/server.XML. Change the port or protocol as needed.

Comment: I add a new connector (port 80) and the android still consumes the web service just fine but I can't access the website using just the domain or www.domain.com:80. Ony if I use the old one: www.domain.com:8080

Comment: Port 80 ( default used by Apache web server) may already be used by some other process. Run check on ports usage...u on Unix or windows?

Comment: Check what is running on port 80 with either netstat command or using netstat -a | grep 80

Comment: It's always advisable to higher ports beyond    4000 as they are kind of reserved these days..80 is generally blocked due to security issues. So best bet is to changed ports and use Apache in front..

Comment: I checked and port 80 is not being used.

Comment: I think I have answered the original question & can expect you to accept my answer before we dig deeper..

Comment: In fact, your answer does not solve my problem, but give me a hint about how can I solve this. I will post what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sheetal Mohan Sharma coment on his answer: "80 is generally blocked due to security issues".

So, this gave me the right direction.
In fact, port 80 is really blocked and the workaround for solve this in linux is to install the **authbind**. But for me, this does not solve the problem, because **authbind** is not available to install in my ec2 instance (e.g. *yum install*).

For finally solve this problem, I followed the tutorial in this site:

http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-advanced.html

The steps are:

1 - *forward incoming port 80 requests to port 8080*

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

2 - *Test it. If with works, you can save this iptables rule*

```
sudo /sbin/service iptables save
```

3 - Like said in the link: *Finally, you need the servlets inside your Web application to act as if the incoming requests were directed to port 80. This will prevent the appearance of the non-privileged port in any URLs sent back to the client. Include the proxyPort attribute in your HTTP connector config in server.xml:*

```
<Connector port="8080" proxyPort="80" .../>
```